# Personal project management

Tags: project-management, knowledge-organization

I'm looking for a tool to manage personal projects. Ideally it would focus less on scheduling aspects (dates, durations) and more on knowledge structure (task relationships, detailed descriptions).

What I have in mind:

- Task dependency: what tasks need to be done before this one can be started, what tasks this one blocks. This is a must.
- A way to write and easily access detailed descriptions. Markdown is preferred for formatting. Nice if it supports attachments.
- Doesn't focus on dates/durations. These are personal projects done in my own time. They will be done when they'll be done. I may chose to spend my time on something else and I don't want to be shamed by the tool that I'm behind the schedule.
- Nice if it supports basic task statuses (open, in progress, done).

I want something to keep track of *what* needs to be done, not *when* it needs to be done. Most tools I tried that provide task dependencies are built around Gantt charts. They provide nice visualization of dependencies but almost universally lack detailed descriptions and are way too attached to calendar.

I like OmniPlan's Network view:
[image]

If only dates/effort could be replaced with descriptions.

MacOS or web-based.

Is there such a thing?